# Symfony 1.4 with TCPDF: How to retrieve data from a database and show it as a .pdf file?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, tcpdf

I work with Symfony 1.4. I want to create a pdf file using TCPDF with the content of a query involving multiple tables.
Here my code in the actions.class.php:

```
public function executeTest()
{ 
     $this->conflictos1s = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Conflictos1')
      ->createQuery('a') 
      ->leftJoin('a.SectorActividadCiuTa7')     
      ->leftJoin('a.RelacionConflictualPrincipalTa9') 
      ->leftJoin('a.SubsectorActividadTa8')       
       ->leftJoin('a.DemandasTa2')      
       ->leftJoin('a.ActoresTa1')     
       ->leftJoin('a.Conflictos1HasActoresTa1')    
      ->orderBy('a.Id DESC')
            ->execute();  

  $config = sfTCPDFPluginConfigHandler::loadConfig();

  // pdf object
  $pdf = new sfTCPDF();

  // set document information
  $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
  $pdf->SetAuthor('J. H.');
  $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
  $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
  $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

  // set default header data
 $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

  // set header and footer fonts
  $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
  $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

  // set default monospaced font
  $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

  //set margins
  $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
  $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
  $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

  //set auto page breaks
  $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

  //set image scale factor
  $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

  // ---------------------------------------------------------

  // set default font subsetting mode
  $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

  // Set font
  // dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
  // print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
  // helvetica or times to reduce file size.
  $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

  // Add a page
  // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Write(0, '', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 6);
  // Set some content to print
 $html = $this->getPartial(
    'generar_pdf', 
    // put in this array all variables you want to give to the partial

   array('posts' => $posts)
  );
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');

  // ---------------------------------------------------------

  // Close and output PDF document
  // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
  $pdf->Output('example_conflictos.pdf', 'I');

  // Stop symfony process
  throw new sfStopException();
}
```

Here my template code (a partial called _generar_pdf.php). I have followed the advice here:
[Using PHP with TCPDF to retrieve data(using mysql) from a database and show it as a .pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153305/using-php-with-tcpdf-to-retreive-datausing-mysql-from-a-database-and-show-it-a/8153558#8153558)

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<h2>Listado de Conflictos</h2>
<table cellspacing="1" border="1">       
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
       <th>Ver acciones<br>conflictivas</th>
      <th>Ver actores</th>
       <th>Fecha comienzo</th>
      <th>Relacion conflictual principal</th>
      <th>Sector actividad</th>
      <th>Subsector actividad</th>
      <th>Demandas</th>      
      <th>Descripcion-general</th>
      <th>Descripcion protagonista</th>
      <th>Descripcion antagonista</th>
      <th>Descripcion demandaprinc</th>
      <th>Nivel estado</th>
      <th>Descripcion sector</th>
      <th>Fecha final</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($conflictos1s as $conflictos1): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getId() ?></a></td>
      <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($conflictos1->getFechaComienzo())) ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getRelacionConflictualPrincipalTa9() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getSectorActividadCiuTa7() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getSubsectorActividadTa8() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDemandasTa2() ?></td>
       <td width="20%"><?php echo substr($conflictos1->getDescripcionGeneral(),0,60) ?></td> 
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDescripcionProtagonista() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDescripcionAntagonista() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDescripcionDemandaprinc() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getNivelEstado() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDescripcionSector() ?></td>
      <td><?php if(!is_null($conflictos1->getFechaFinal())){ echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($conflictos1->getFechaFinal()));} ?></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>      
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php $posts = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 
echo $posts ?>
```

Here my result:
[image: PDF file]
I can not see the variable data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AlexeyGerasimov Hi, can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Is the query made in your action correct? Are you sure there are some rows in your result? Have you debugged it?

Comment: @ilSalvo The query is OK. If I create a template testSuccess.php and annulled in the action all that is below the query, symfony generates a correct view of all data. What I can not do is that the query is read by the TCPDF library

Comment: Maybe becouse you pass to the partial a $posts array, but in the template you cycle through a $conflictos1s. Try to change the cycle array you cycle through, from $conflictos to posts, in the partial

Comment: @ilSalvo I found the solution!. Now I perfect it. I divided the actions of two parts. First I create an action `executeTest()` with the query  and call the template `testSuccess`. In the template, the first line is: `<?php ob_start();?>` and the latter are: `<?php $posts = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); ?>
<?php $sf_user->setAttribute('para_pdf', $posts); ?>`
Then pass the variable `$posts` to a second actions that creates the pdf, with all data.

Comment: nice to know you've founded the right solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution I encountered: I've separated the problem in two. First, I built an actions with the query: the actions have called `executeTest` (see the code below)

```
public function executeTest()
{ 
     $this->conflictos1s = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Conflictos1')
      ->createQuery('a') 
      ->leftJoin('a.SectorActividadCiuTa7')     
      ->leftJoin('a.RelacionConflictualPrincipalTa9') 
      ->leftJoin('a.SubsectorActividadTa8')       
       ->leftJoin('a.DemandasTa2')      
       ->leftJoin('a.ActoresTa1')     
       ->leftJoin('a.Conflictos1HasActoresTa1')    
      ->orderBy('a.Id')
      ->execute();  
}
```

Then I built a template named `testSuccess.php`. So far nothing new in Symfony 1.4. But in this template, I added the following lines of code. At first:

`<?php ob_start(); ?>`

Last of all, in the template I wrote:

`<?php $posts = ob_get_contents(); ?>`

`<?php ob_end_clean(); ?>`

The view content is recorded in the variable `$posts`

```
//testSuccess.php

<?php ob_start(); ?>


<h2>Listado de Conflictos</h2>
<table cellspacing="1" border="1">       
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="2%">Id</th>
       <th width="6%">Fecha comienzo</th>
      <th>Relacion conflictual principal</th>
      <th>Sector actividad</th>
      <th>Subsector actividad</th>
      <th>Demandas</th>      
      <th width="20%">Descripcion-general</th>
      <th>Descripcion protagonista</th>
      <th>Descripcion antagonista</th>
      <th>Descripcion demandaprinc</th>
      <th>Nivel estado</th>
      <th>Descripcion sector</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($conflictos1s as $conflictos1): ?>
    <tr>
      <td width="2%"><?php echo $conflictos1->getId() ?></td>
      <td width="6%"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($conflictos1->getFechaComienzo())) ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getRelacionConflictualPrincipalTa9() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getSectorActividadCiuTa7() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getSubsectorActividadTa8() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDemandasTa2() ?></td>
       <td width="20%"><?php echo substr($conflictos1->getDescripcionGeneral(),0,60).'...' ?></td> 
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDescripcionProtagonista() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDescripcionAntagonista() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDescripcionDemandaprinc() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getNivelEstado() ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $conflictos1->getDescripcionSector() ?></td>   
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>      
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php $posts = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); ?>
<?php $sf_user->setAttribute('para_pdf', $posts); ?>
 <a href="<?php echo url_for('conflictos/testpdf') ?>">Generar Pdf</a>
```

This idea was taken from the answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029908/alexey-gerasimov  here:

[Using PHP with TCPDF to retrieve data(using mysql) from a database and show it as a .pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153305/using-php-with-tcpdf-to-retreive-datausing-mysql-from-a-database-and-show-it-a/8153558#8153558)

In this template we generate the view and capture everything the browser "write". I add a link to generate now the PDF `<a href="<?php echo url_for('conflictos/testpdf') ?>">Generar Pdf</a>`.  It passes the contents of the variable `$posts` to new actions `testpdf`, through Symfony's user class:

`<?php $sf_user->setAttribute('para_pdf', $posts); ?>`

It call for a new actions named `testpdf`. In the new action `executeTestpdf`, pay attention to the following line of code, which retrieve the value of the variable `$posts`:

`$ html = $ this-> getUser () -> getAttribute ('para_pdf');`

```
public function executeTestpdf()
{       
  $config = sfTCPDFPluginConfigHandler::loadConfig();

  // pdf object
  $pdf = new sfTCPDF();

  // set document information
  $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
  $pdf->SetAuthor('J. H.');
  $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
  $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
  $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

  // set default header data
 $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

  // set header and footer fonts
  $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
  $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

  // set default monospaced font
  $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

  //set margins
  $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
  $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
  $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

  //set auto page breaks
  $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

  //set image scale factor
  $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

  // ---------------------------------------------------------
 $pdf->setPageOrientation("L");


  // set default font subsetting mode
  $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

  // Set font
  $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 6);

  // Add a page
  // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Write(0, '', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);


  // Set some content to print


 $html = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('para_pdf');


  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');

  // ---------------------------------------------------------

  // Close and output PDF document
  // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
  $pdf->Output('example_conflictos.pdf', 'I');

  // Stop symfony process
  throw new sfStopException();
}
```

Then, finally I have the PDF generated with all data properly shown!.

Comment: See Spanish version here: http://symfonyandme.com/2014/01/23/symfony-1-4-y-tcpdf/

Comment: See Spanish version for Symfony 2.8, here: http://symfonyandme.com/2016/05/26/symfony-2-8-y-tcpdf/